# How to get current date directly from internet in asp.net (not system date)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an app with booking engine. So basically I need a date from internet.

```
System.DateTime.Now
```

I have used this but it returns me current (local) system date. I don't want system date because it can be changed at client's end. So I am looking for Internet (UTC) date.

Comment: How server date can be changed on client?

Comment: What stops them from changing the so called *date from internet* ? your question is vaugue, can you explain the exact scenario you want this for. (*and ofcourse what is a date from the internet?*)

Comment: How accurate does it need to be? By the time you've connected to a server, the server has computed the time, and it's been sent back to a client and actually read, it's no longer the same time on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net System.DateTime.Now returns the time of the *server*, not the *client*. This has no bearing to the date and time on a clients computer.

If you *really* want to get the date from a different server, try [this](http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/c-get-nist-internet-time/).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
DateTime.UtcNow
```

that will give you current UTC date and then you can change it for different timezones by adding hours to it or can just use it as a standard date.

Answer (score -1):

Get date using javascript and store it in hidden field.

document.getElementById("hdnTime").value = new Date();

then get client date from hidden variable in server side.

Comment: He specifically said internet time, __not__ client time